what's the best practice to define Model in swift
I have a model Answer like this
struct Answer: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var created: String
    var modified: String
    var updatedAt: String
    var createdBy: String
    ...
}

And because I have this model conforms to Codable, the default initializer is removed .
And when I want create a default object of this model:
var answerModel: Answer = Answer()

It can't work and complains that
Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call

because the init(from:Decoder) defined in Codable protocol , remove the default init method.
So I have to add default value for each property in the model .
But I think this is too tedius when there are too many properties in a model .
Is there any pretty way to make a model conforms to Codable , and still can be created using default initializer?

...the default initializer is removed, no it is created for you by the system.
So if you want to create a Answer, use this:
var answerModel = Answer(id: 0, created: "", modified: "", updatedAt: "", createdBy: "", ...)

You can’t do Answer() either way. For that to work, your properties must all have an initial value.

Thanks @workingdog support Ukraine
, seems I am messing with the default initializer and the memberwise initializer

Thanks @Sweeper , So If I have a struct have more than 20 properties , It' better to to give a default value for each of them explicitly ?
